# Vuejs - Getting 404 when reload the product page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

In vue project when i go to product detail page from home page it works, but when i reload the product detail page, it returns 404, also when i access the product page directly it return 404. It works only when i go by clicking on product.

This issue is on production (server) only. In localhost it is working perfectly.

When i add this to htaccess it works but home page comes first for a second.

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

I am new to vuejs. Hope someone can help with this. Thanks.

Comment: Is mod rewrite enabled from your hosting provider? Sometimes you need to dig in the settings and manually enable it.

Comment: @NLxDoDge yes it is enabled

Comment: Checked the deployment page of the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used async and await and it worked for me.

```js
async fetch() {
  await axios.get();
}
```

Comment: What? Not sure to understand how this answer is related to the issue. Quite cryptic I have to say. You were using `asyncData` before maybe?

Comment: @kissu dynamic urls (product detail page) were not working... I found that when i use async, urls work... for testing i added async to get products of particular products... urls worked for that particular category and not for others... now i added async to shop page so now all the product detail page's urls are working... i am still stying to understand this how it worked, but it solved my issue.

Comment: For sure, work on writing decent questions. Your question provide not enough of code, so no one could help you.

Comment: Ok sorry for that... i will provide enough information in future. Thanks

Comment: Also, I don't see why something like this would work locally but not on production. Anyway, for async requests use `async/await` for sure.